# NSLocalizedString does not work on killing and restarting app on iphone 5 (ios 8)

Tags: objective-c, iphone, localizable.strings

I created a Localizable.strings file in XCode and then 2 languages in it.(en and fr).

If I try something like:

```
self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Shop", @"");
```

This works fine when I am running app and changing languages but when I am killing app and restarting the app then I am not able to get correct values for changed language. It is setting values for English language only.

Any idea ?

Comment: How do you change the languages when your app is running?

Comment: By using NSBundle method : + (void)setLanguage:(NSString *)language;

Comment: Isn't that a custom method? If YES, you just have to save your last language set?

Comment: Yes, I am saving last language selected and able to get selected language too. But not the correct values for keys. Getting strings values saved from default language. As  - (NSString *)localizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value table:(NSString *)tableName this method is not getting called. Why this is not getting called when application goes into background after changing the language to french.